# Show that the following function defined by an integral is uniformly continuous

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, uniform-continuity

Consider $\phi: C([a,b]) \to R$ given by
$$f \to \int_{a}^ b f dx$$
Show that $\phi$ is uniformly continuous.

Not really sure where to start here. It seems like I'm given very little. I'm given information about f, not $\phi$, and $f$ is not equal to that integral, it is mapped to there because of the arrow. So I'm not really sure what to do with what is given. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Which distance are you using on $C([a,b])$? And on $\Bbb R$?

Comment: If you combine everything that the questions gives you, it is really saying that
$$\phi[f(x)]=\int_a^bf(x)dx$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inequality

$$\vert \phi(f) - \phi (g) \vert =\left\vert \int_a^b \ f(x)\ dx - \int_a^b \ g(x)\ dx \right\vert \le (b-a) \Vert f - g \Vert$$

where $$ \Vert f-g\Vert= \sup_{x \in [a,b]} \vert f(x) -g(x) \vert$$

proves that $\phi$ is $(b-a)$-Lipschitz and is sufficient to get your desired conclusion. Providing that $\mathcal C([a,b], \mathbb R)$ is equipped with the $\sup$ norm.

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I totally didn't see that when I was looking at it. Thank you!